# Wordpress - mudança de pasta para raiz

Tags: wordpress

Estou para montar um site em *wordpress* para a agência de um amigo.

Por enquanto, ao acessar o site, temos um arquivo html informando que o site esta em construção.

Mas agora que vamos desenvolver o site em *wordpress*, eu pensei em instalar em uma subpasta e quando publicar, puxar para a raiz, mas já me disseram que isso da muito problema.

Existe uma forma segura de fazer isso, sem perder os posts e configurações do tema?

Existe uma forma de instalar o *wordpress* na raiz do site, mas deixar ele escondido dos usuários durante o desenvolvimento, talvez somente acessando o site por senha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe sim, existe um plugin chamado "WP Construction Mode".
Só quem tem acesso ao site/portal, será quem estiver logado.
Quem estiver deslogado(do wordpress), terá uma página parecida com essa...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No próprio wordpress, na parte de plugins você encontra esse plugin, ou você pode baixar em: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-construction-mode/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Algumas configurações que você pode fazer, é bem fácil de usar, ao concluir o site, basta desativa-lo.